# Open Graph Object books.book publishing fails

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an object in the Developer App page and followed the code shown in "Get Code".  Facebook user login all went well, but when I started to post to the test user account, I got the "Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter" error message.

[image]

My code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:myImage
                                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
           NSString *urlOfStagedImage = [result objectForKey:@"uri"];
           if (urlOfStagedImage) {
                NSMutableDictionary <FBGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"books.book"
                                                                                                      title:@"My title"
                                                                                                      image:urlOfStagedImage
                                                                                                        url:@"http://www.myurl.com"
                                                                                                description:@"My description"];
                [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/books.book"
                                                   graphObject:object
                                             completionHandler:^[FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                       if (!error) {
                          // Published.
                          NSLog(@"Published");
                       } else {
                          // Show error.
                       }
                 }];
        } else {
             // Show error.
        }
}];
```

I changed @"me/objects/books.book" to @"me".  There was no error, the message "Published" was displayed on the console, but the post did not show up on the test user's timeline.

I cannot find problem with the code.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the activity log of the test user? Posting to @"me" should work. Can you get an ID of the published story?

Comment: It did not show up on the activity log and the id is null.

Comment: Just to be sure; you are using a Test User as made available by your app, using the Developer Dashboard, right? Not just any account? Have you checked the session and publish_actions permission available to this user?

Comment: Yes, the Test User account is set up through Facebook Roles -> Test Users, using the Developer Dashboard.  Publish permissions are all good.  ISBN is required under books.book object properties.  It might be I have to enter the ISBN.